# Why does an array field in a Go struct default to null when inserted into mongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, go, postman

So I have ran into some unexpected behavior when inserting a model into mongoDB. When I send an empty body via Postman to my server and insert it into my database, the returned result to Postman had `name` and `number` default to their expected default values, `0` and `""`, but for `data`, instead of defaulting to an empty array, it defaulted to `null` instead, even though its value printed out before and after insertion in the Go console isn't nil, but an empty array. Assigning the `data` field an empty `[]int{}` before insertion solves the issue, and so does manually sending an empty array as the data field from Postman, but I was curious if there was any other way to guarantee that array fields default to `[]` and not `null` when getting inserted.

Here is my model:

```
type Test struct{
    Name string `json:"name"   bson:"name"`
    Number int  `json:"number" bson:"number"`
    Data []int  `json:"data"   bson:"data"`
}
```

Comment: *"even though its value printed out before and after insertion in the Go console isn't nil"* -- `[]` can be `nil` and it can be an empty slice, see: https://go.dev/play/p/RSmPq36s3YY.

Answer (score 1):

> Implement bson.Marshaler, and your MarshalBSON() function will be called when you save values

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

type Test struct {
    Data []int `json:"data" bson:"data"`
}

func (t *Test) MarshalBSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if t.Data == nil {
        log.Println("t.Data is nil")
        t.Data = make([]int, 0)
    }

    type my Test
    return bson.Marshal((*my)(t))
}

func main() {
    h := Test{}
    data, _ := bson.Marshal(&h)
    log.Print(bson.Raw(data))
}

// output: 
// 2009/11/10 23:00:00 t.Data is nil
// 2009/11/10 23:00:00 {"data": []}
```

demo go playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/1WlO_44hnco

also, you can check this link: [Autofill created_at and updated_at in golang struct while pushing into mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71902455/autofill-created-at-and-updated-at-in-golang-struct-while-pushing-into-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You can define a registry for your collection (or database) using mgocompat package.

```
import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/mgocompat"

...........
    
db := client.Database(dbName, options.Database().SetRegistry(mgocompat.NewRegistryBuilder().Build()))
```